# How can I resolve 'Unable to find a match: buildah podman' error when installing on RHEL 8.7?

Tags: rhel, podman, buildah

I am trying to install **buildah** and **podman** on my **rhel 8.7**

After running `dnf install buildah podman -y`

I received this error. I tried to look for a solution on google but I am unable to find any.
Please advise.

```
[root@localhost tmp]# dnf install buildah podman -y
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:14:16 ago on Mon 29 May 2023 11:32:47 PM PDT.
No match for argument: buildah
No match for argument: podman
Error: Unable to find a match: buildah podman
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your rhel 8,7 is "outdated". I suggest you follow this [article](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/6394941) and run the commands. After this, try running `dnf install buildah podman -y`, it should work now.